# When does Chris realize his feelings?

Tags: plot-explanation, just-friends

In the film [*Just Friends* (2005)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0433400/), when exactly does Chris realize his feelings for Jamie? I mean, I know he has feelings for her, but when he first arrives back in New Jersey he thinks he's only interested in sleeping with her.

Is it the moment when they're lying in bed together, or is it before that that his true feelings come to light?

Answer (score 1):

I always felt he always had feelings for her, but knew he was "friend-zoned" and accepted that their relationship would never go further.  If you remember, there's a scene where he writes his feelings for her in her yearbook when they were in HS, and then gets ridiculed at a keg party by all the "cool kids" who found Jaime's yearbook and his confession.

So, when they meet up again later, Chris initially does just want to sleep with her, but then decided her friendship was more important than a conquest.  There's a scene where he intends to tell Jaime how he feels at her family Christmas party, but gets blocked by Dinkleman.

So, to answer your question, it's *before* they spend the night together that his true intentions are known to the audience, as that was the night following the Christmas party.  But it's *while* they're in bed that Jaime finally understands it.